# Use SimulatedLocationDataSource to mock a timeout?

Tags: .net, xamarin, esri

I am developing a Xamarin app that uses the ArcGIS Runtime API for .NET. We have a user who is experiencing crashes when the "Locate Me" function of the map times out. It's very difficult to reproduce this issue without driving myself to somewhere with a low signal. I recently found the `SimulatedLocationDataSource` class which seems at least very close to what I need. Is there any way I can get it to simulate a timeout? I thought perhaps the `StartTime` property would do the trick, but I am unsure how it works, and can't find any documentation explaining it.

In fact the only documentation I can find is here: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/device-location/#simulate-device-location-updates

And here: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Location.SimulatedLocationDataSource.html

Comment: If the problem is in your code (not code beneath you), then simply add a delay long enough to trigger your timeout handler.

Comment: If you want to `simulate a timeout`, you can limit the speed of your test device. In addition, maybe you also can try the Thread.Sleep() or the Task.Delay().

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I think of that... I am not sure if the problem is our code, Xamarin or Esri or some combination, or somewhere else, I am very new to this codebase